# Changing values using regex or a certain software, depending on a certain value, on a XML file

Tags: regex, xml

I got an XML file with around 1000 codes, each code has the following structure:

```
<codes>
        <code name="901" description="CONIFERADENSA BORDE" tags="Poligonos" type="1" command="" helpFile="" table="ARBOLADO" CONDITIONS="id_tipo=0122,IDIOMA=0,COMPONEN1D=2,DENSIDAD=1,TIPO_0122=1,PLANT_0122=2" enabled="1" print="1" streamMode="0">
            <ccc:Triggers>
            </ccc:Triggers>
            <representation style="continuous" color="77" color-stereo="219" width="1" width-stereo="1" print-color="0" print-width="0.010000" font="0" italic="0" />
            <io>
                <iobin:transform code="901"/>
                <iobind:transform code="901"/>
                <iocsv:transform type="0" />
                <iodgn:transform level="54" colorEntity="2" styleEntity="0" weightEntity="1" gg="901" class="0" color="2" style="0" weight="1" >
                    <iodgn:point type="POINT" cell="" sx="1.000000" sy="1.000000" />
                    <iodgn:line type="LINESTRING" />
                    <iodgn:text font="STANDARD" />
                </iodgn:transform>
                <iodwg:transform layer="901">
                    <iodwg:line type="Polyline3D"/>
                    <iodwg:point type="Point"/>
                    <iodwg:text style="Standard" oblique="0.000000" />
                </iodwg:transform>
                <ioGeomedia:transform table="CUBIERTATER_LIN" textHeight="1.000000" />
                <iokml:transform type="0" elevation="0" extrude="0" opacity="255" />
                <ioshp:transform nameSHP="CUBIERTATER_LIN" typeNewTable="13" />
                <iosvg:transform stroke-width="1.000000" stroke="#44382b" stroke-linejoin="miter" stroke-linecap="butt" fill="0" fill-color="#44382b" point-size="1.000000" />
            </io>
        </code>
```

what i need to do is to change the ioshp:transform.nameSHP value with the same value that is on the code.table, so if the example has the code.table value equal to "Arbolado", the ioshp:tansform.nameSHP needs to be also "Arbolado".

Could you help me with this? i'm trying to use regex on notepad++ to make it quicker, but i'm being uncapable so far...

Comment: nothing like stoppping, eating a cheesecake and getting back to work. This was my solution, hope it helps someone:

>>>   Search  \n\r
>>>    replace with nothing
>>>    Search  nameSHP=”
>>>    replace with  nameSHP=”;
>>>    Search (nameSHP=”;([^”])*”)
>>>    replace with nameSHP=”;\1;”
>>>    Search  " (table="([^"])*")([^;]*);([^;]*);
>>>    replace with: " \1\3\1"
>>>    Search nameSHP=”table=”
>>>    replace with nameSHP=”
>>>    Search  “”;”
>>>    replace with “

Answer (score -1):

You need to use re.sub regex:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"(<code[^>]*table=\"(ARBOLADO)\"[^>]*>.*?<ioshp\:transform\s+nameSHP=\")(?!ARBOLADO).*?(\"[^>]*>.*?<\/code>)", r"\1\2\3", YOUR_STRING)
```

Comment: i think you're supposing too much... the code.table value varies in each code. That's the main issue. So, for code.name="901" the code.table value is "arbolado", but for code.name="905", the code.table value is "camino", and so on.... Also, please, tell me where are you doing that, or how, as i think it won't work on notepad++